# Electron1.8.1 で apng が正常に表示できない不具合

Tags: html5, google-chrome, electron

Electron1.8.1 で apng ( 49コマ / 17.0MB ) の再生が正常にできません。
ループする前後で処理落ちをしているうかのような乱れ方をします。乱れ方は一定です。

プリビルドかビルドかによって結果は変わりません。
なお、Electron ではなく、通常の Chrome で同じ画面を開いた場合には問題なく表示されます。

類似の症状や、解決法に心当たりある方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか？

Comment: 現状返信がありませんが、この issue ですかね……。 https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11443

Comment: 自分は Windows 環境なので違いますが、Electron の apng 再生機能には不安があるのは確かっぽいですね……。試しに、4MB までファイルサイズを落としたもので確認しましたが、同様の症状がでました。apng を Electron で正常再生できたことがある人がいれば、簡単に環境をお聞きしたいところです。解答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 私が言及した issue では Electron 1.8.2-beta.3 が Windows 環境下で apng を再生できていると書いているので、Electron のバージョンを上げてみるのも一手かもしれません。

Comment: Windows の Electron 1.8.2-beta.3 で試しましたが、ダメですね。しばらく更新待ちでいこうかと思います。ありがとうございました。